# Syntax of ruby function type in a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

If I have a class in Ruby:

```
class Person
  def get_person

  end

  protected
  def check_person_1

  end
  def check_person_2

  end

  private
  def auth_person_1

  end
  def auth_person_2

  end

end
```

is `auth_person_2` a **private** function or **public** or **protected** function? I mean I do not have the "**private**" keyword above the function name, but it is under the `auth_person_1` function which is however directly under "**private**", what function type `auth_person_2` is in this case? and how about function `check_person_2` ?

Answer (score 2):

in this case auth_person1/2 would be private, check_person1/2 would be protected and get_person would be public.

Functions look for the last keyword and that's what they use.

You can also do it this way :

```
class Person
def method1
end
def method2
end
def method3
end
def method4
end

public :method1, :method4
protected :method2
private :method3

end
```

Doing something like this would also work :

```
class Person
def method
end

private
def method1
end

public
def method2
end
end
```

You can have them in any order and use the same keyword more than once.

Comment: Slight correction: Functions do not 'look for last keyword'; `private`, `protected` are methods from the `Kernel` module. These methods set the access scope.

Comment: And they aren't functions, they are methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is not like C# where you have to define the encapsulation for each method.

Everything bellow the method "private" is private until you call one of the other methods (private, public or protected). For example, you can use "public" to define a public method after a block of private ones.

By default your class is public.

```
class Hello
  ...
end
```

is the same as

```
class Hello
  public
  ...
end
```

Comment: `private` is not a keyword, it's a method just like pretty much everything else in Ruby.

Comment: It doesn't *really* matter *until* some third-party library author comes up with the very bright idea of *monkey-patching* `private`. *That* was a fun bug to track down ... NOT.